# FXCop Custom Rule does not show up in RuleSet

Tags: c#, fxcop

I followed the steps here to create a new custom rule and add it to the ruleset in VSStudio 2013:

http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2010/01/06/custom-code-analysis-rules-in-vs2010-and-how-to-make-them-run-in-fxcop-and-vs2008-too/

However, despite all my efforts, the custom rule does not show up in the ruleset file.

If I add the rule in the FXCop Editor, it shows up and analyzes the target project correctly.

This is the Rule File, which is an **embedded resource** in the project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Rules FriendlyName="PSI Custom FxCop Rules">
<Rule TypeName="EnforceHungarianNotation" Category="PSIRules" CheckId="CR0001">
<Name>Enforce Hungarian Notation</Name>
<Description>Checks fields for compliance with Hungarian notation.</Description>
<Resolution>Field {0} is not in Hungarian notation. Field name should be prefixed with '{1}'.</Resolution>
<MessageLevel Certainty="100">Error</MessageLevel>
<FixCategories>Breaking</FixCategories>
<Url />
<Owner />
<Email />
</Rule>
</Rules>
```

This is my RuleSet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RuleSet Name="New Rule Set" Description=" " ToolsVersion="10.0">
         <RuleHintPaths>       
             <Path>C:\App\PSI\Development\Source\JHA.ProfitStars.PSI\JHA.ProfitStars  
                   .PSI.FxCop\bin\Debug</Path>
         </RuleHintPaths>
    </RuleSet>
```

I even tried adding the line below, but now it shows an **Unknown** rule in the ruleset:

```
    <Rules AnalyzerId="Microsoft.Analyzers.ManagedCodeAnalysis"  
         RuleNamespace="Microsoft.Rules.Managed">
         <Rule Id="CR0001" Action="Error" />
    </Rules>
```

Could someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong here?

Edited:

BaseClass for rules:

```
internal abstract class BaseFxCopRule : BaseIntrospectionRule
{
    protected BaseFxCopRule(string ruleName)
        : base(ruleName, "JHA.ProfitStars.PSI.FxCop.Rules", typeof(BaseFxCopRule).Assembly)
    { }
}
```

Rules Class:

```
internal sealed class EnforceHungarianNotation : BaseFxCopRule
{
    public EnforceHungarianNotation()
        : base("EnforceHungarianNotation")
    { 
    }

    public override TargetVisibilities TargetVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            return TargetVisibilities.NotExternallyVisible;
        }
    }

    public override ProblemCollection Check(Member member)
    {
        Field field = member as Field;
        if (field == null)
        {
            // This rule only applies to fields.
            // Return a null ProblemCollection so no violations are reported for this member.
            return null;
        }

        if (field.IsStatic)
        {
            CheckFieldName(field, s_staticFieldPrefix);
        }
        else
        {
            CheckFieldName(field, s_nonStaticFieldPrefix);
        }

        // By default the Problems collection is empty so no violations will be reported
        // unless CheckFieldName found and added a problem.
        return Problems;
    }
    private const string s_staticFieldPrefix = "s_";
    private const string s_nonStaticFieldPrefix = "m_";

    private void CheckFieldName(Field field, string expectedPrefix)
    {
        if (!field.Name.Name.StartsWith(expectedPrefix, StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            Resolution resolution = GetResolution(
              field,  // Field {0} is not in Hungarian notation.
              expectedPrefix  // Field name should be prefixed with {1}.
              );
            Problem problem = new Problem(resolution);
            Problems.Add(problem);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First, I'd remove the unneeded tags as `asp.net` and `MVC` have nothing to do with your rules. Try adding the .dll file into your FxCop directory for Visual Studio: `Microsoft Visual Studio [Version]\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\Rules`

Comment: Sorry, the spaces were added while I was uploading the question. It's not in the actual file

Comment: Did the placing of the file into your FxCop-rules location solve the problem?

Comment: No, that still does not show the rule in the ruleset.

Comment: Can you show me the actual rule file including its name?

Comment: Edited with the rules classes

Comment: Is your rules xml also named `JHA.ProfitStars.PSI.FxCop.Rules`?

Comment: Yes the Rules file is Rules.xml, JHA.ProfitStars.PSI.FxCop is the namespace

Comment: Are you showing all available rules in Visual Studio?

Comment: I need to do a POC to show how Custom Rules can be added to a project via Code Analysis. I am able to do it for VS Microsoft predefined rules, but unable to show the custom rule in the ruleset, and thereby in the code analysis tab.

Comment: I was facing the same problem, and updating the ToolsVersion="10.0" to version of Visual Studio in use in my RuleSet file solved my issue. Also make sure that FxCop dependency dll are also from same Tools folder of that of your Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your path is kind of shaky, remove some spacing and unwanted characters:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RuleSet Name="New Rule Set" Description=" " ToolsVersion="10.0">
     <RuleHintPaths>       
         <Path>C:\App\PSI\Development\Source\JHA.ProfitStars.PSI\JHA.ProfitStars.PSI.FxCop\bin\Debug</Path>
     </RuleHintPaths>
</RuleSet>
```

Also adding the rulesdll to `Microsoft Visual Studio [Version]\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\Rules`location would solve the issue of having to use Rulehintpaths.

As I can't detect anything wrong with your custom rules, see if you have selected the option to show all rules:

[image]

Also, using the following BaseRule might help:

```
protected BaseRule(string name)
        : base(

            // The name of the rule (must match exactly to an entry
            // in the manifest XML)
            name,

            // The name of the manifest XML file, qualified with the
            // namespace and missing the extension
            typeof(BaseRule).Assembly.GetName().Name + ".Rules",

            // The assembly to find the manifest XML in
            typeof(BaseRule).Assembly)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help on this, this far. I've actually already tried both of the above, as they are suggested online as well, but something's wrong somewhere and this still refuses to work!

Comment: I've actually built a dll using your exact files and it worked. The rule is showing up in my ruleset explorer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why it's not working. I'm marking your answer as the answer anyway, because it is correct. Thanks again.

Comment: Just to make sure, I've done the same thing, I created 2 projects. The first has the custom rule (EnforceHungarianNotation and the embedded Rules.xml file). The next project has a Code Analysis file added. I changed the hint path and later added the previous project's output dll to the FXCop dir. This project is a class library with no other references.

Comment: I have one project. Which, in your case, should be named JHA.ProfitStars.PSI.FxCop. In this you have two classes, your baserule and the enforcehungariannotation. Third in this classlibrary is an embedded resource Rules.xml

Comment: In that case, where are you able to see the newly added rule?

Comment: In my ruleset explorer, in Visual Studio. Add your custom rule dll into FxCop/Rules. Placing it in Rulesfolder is essential. Then show all available rules as shown in the image provided and it should show up. Create a new ruleset file and select your rule there.

Comment: I'm curious to know what is wrong. Any way I can share my custom dll with you and you copy it to the FXCop location and let me know if it shows up still?

Comment: I would start over with your rule and follow this tutorial: http://weblogs.asp.net/uruit/writing-custom-rules-for-tfs-2008-code-analysis-check-in-policy

Answer (score 0):

Close your solution. Use the Source Control Explorer to locate your Rule Set File. Doubleclick onto your ruleset. The Rule Set Editor now should show all your custom rules. If this still doesn't work, try to use a relative path in the Path tag of the RuleHintPaths section.

Have a look at the LoadFromFile() method of the Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeAnalysis.dll:

```
public static RuleSet LoadFromFile(string filePath, IEnumerable<RuleInfoProvider> ruleProviders)
    {
      RuleSet ruleSet = RuleSetXmlProcessor.ReadFromFile(filePath);
      if (ruleProviders != null)
      {
        string relativePathBase = string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath) ? (string) null : Path.GetDirectoryName(ruleSet.FilePath);
        Dictionary<RuleInfoProvider, RuleInfoCollection> allRulesByProvider;
        Dictionary<string, IRuleInfo> rules = RuleSet.GetRules((IEnumerable<string>) ruleSet.RuleHintPaths, ruleProviders, relativePathBase, out allRulesByProvider);
        foreach (RuleReference ruleReference in (Collection<RuleReference>) ruleSet.Rules)
        {
          IRuleInfo ruleInfo;
          if (rules.TryGetValue(ruleReference.FullId, out ruleInfo))
          {
            if (ruleInfo.AnalyzerId == ruleReference.AnalyzerId)
              ruleReference.RuleInfo = ruleInfo;
            else
              CATrace.Info("RuleSet.LoadFromFile: Rule {0} was listed under analyzer id {1} in the rule set, but the corresponding IRuleInfo returned analyzer id {2}", (object) ruleReference.FullId, (object) ruleReference.AnalyzerId, (object) ruleInfo.AnalyzerId);
          }
        }
      }
      return ruleSet;
    }
```

If the relativePathBase is calculated wrong, the rule DLLs will not be found.