# Creating custom written rulesets for Visual Studio Enterprise 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am working on a project that requires custom written rulesets. The problem I am running into is getting my rules to show up under the ruleset editor so that I can choose the rules I have written. The only sources of information I have been able (except 1 which will follow) to find all point me to the existing rules within VS and do not explain how I can get to where I can select my own rules.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/codeanalysis/2010/03/26/how-to-write-custom-static-code-analysis-rules-and-integrate-them-into-visual-studio-2010/

The one source I found that explained what im trying to do seemed a bit vague to me and myself and another attempted to follow what it was saying under the "Running custom rules" paragraph about copying files to the rulesets folder but nothing is working. If anyone has some insite it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen Code Fix and Code Analyzer? They are part of VS2015 and writing rules is much easier ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn904670.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/%C2%ADmagazine/dn879356 ). In addition they are live, meaning: the analyzer shows his results while writing code

Comment: So, I am doing an internship to finish my degree and I am still new to this but I am attempting to implement company coding standards into VS and just recalled that however we do it now has to be able to be done on Team Foundation Server becuse that is where they ultimately want the rulesets implemented so that it can be used accross the entire development team.

Comment: On a side note you can try NDepend that integrates into VS2015 and let's write custom rules easily as C# LINQ queries    http://www.ndepend.com/default-rules/webframe.html   http://www.ndepend.com/features/cqlinq#CQL

Comment: The issue is not writing the rule itself. Once I build the rule and copy the .dll into the fxcop/rules folder and then run Ruleset explorer in VS my rule never shows up. No matter what I try my rule does not show up in the ruleset explorer.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a bit late, but I had the exact same problem as you: **how do I turn a dll into a ruleset?** [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24268335/2119562) answer helped me out a great deal. In case that link goes down: Add a empty new ruleset to your project with Add > New Item. Open it in a text editor, and it'll look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RuleSet Name="New Rule Set" Description=" " ToolsVersion="10.0">
</RuleSet>
```

Edit it to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RuleSet Name="New Rule Set" Description=" " ToolsVersion="10.0">
 <RuleHintPaths>       
         <Path>C:\Path\To\The\Folder\With\The\DLL\In\It\bin\Debug</Path>
 </RuleHintPaths>
</RuleSet>
```

Go to your project's properties, then the Code Analysis tab, and select your RuleSet there. That caused the rules to appear in the list of selectable rules.